# Adding script conditionally

Tags: theming, 8, configuration

In the module I am developing I need to add script which require jQuery.The will be added depending on configuration settings. Hence I am using `template_preprocess_module(&$variables)` where I am trying to add script by doing something like this:

```
function template_preprocess_module(&$variables) {
  if (TRUE) {
    $variables['jquery'] = ?;
    $variables['script'] = 'path to script in module';
  }
}
```

Then in the template I will simply be rendering these variable in the head section. But I am facing trouble in adding jQuery, because I don't know its source (obviously I know its source in core but I need something over here which automates path). Can the source be known by using something like `drupal_get_path()` ? I am also not sure if this is the best way to add script conditionally, any suggestion regarding this? Thanks.

Comment: The question is not quite clear; what exactly are you trying to do? Maybe an example would help.

Comment: @Topsitemakers I have updated the question.Does this help?

Comment: which drupal version you are using?

Answer (score 5):

To attach a script in Drupal 8 you need to define a library first in your modules `*.libraries.yml` (replace * with your modules machine name).
The file should look as follows:

```
libraryname:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/script.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

After that you have the possibilities to attach a script through a preprocess function or directly in the template with a twig function.
I believe you are trying to achieve the first. In that case you need to modify the render array, like in this example:

```
<?php
function modulename_element_info_alter(array &$types) {
  if (isset($types['table'])) {
    $types['table']['#attached']['library'][] = 'modulename/libraryname';
  }
}
?>
```

If you want to append a script to every page depending if a custom setting is activated in your module, you should do as follows:

```
function modulename_page_attachments_alter(array &$page) {
  if ($settingIsTrue) {
    $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'modulename/libraryname';
  }
}
```

You can read more about it in the [manual](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets).

Comment: thanks for your answer but I have already seen this in the documentation and it didn't suited my requirements.Anyways do u have some ideas related to manner I have suggested above?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing? Do you have problems choosing the right hook? Or is jquery your problem? Adding jquery as a dependency to your script is really easy, see my edit.

Comment: I am trying to add both jquery and script in twig template hence I am needing to prepare variable by doing pre-processing.But then I am not able to add jQuery present in the core becoz I am having trouble in knowing its source. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You should do it as in my last edit. This hook allows you to attach a script to every page depending on your special conditions. If you add jquery as a dependency in your *.libraries.yml it will be attached automatically before your script.

Comment: thanks for showing patience in answering.One last thing please do tell me if u know a way to find path of jQuery present in core(using some function of Drupal 8).Thanks.

Comment: If you want to add jQuery programmatically you should do it this way: `$page['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/jquery';`
Please don't forget to vote if the answers helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add jQuery directly in a twig template using the new Drupal 8 `attach_library()` twig function:

```
{# my_template.html.twig #}
<div>
{# This will add jQuery to this template only #}
{{ attach_library('core/jquery') }}
</div>
```