# In Drupal 8 Javascript is not enabled by default on all pages? How can I enable it for specific pages?

Tags: 8

How can I enable the javascript or jQuery in certain pages in Drupal 8? Any example will be really helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you read [that question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/104091/how-to-add-css-javasript-to-head-section-of-drupal-8), or [that one](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161384/adding-script-conditionally)?

Comment: Thank you Alex for your comment. I could not find that question at that time. So I started reading the whole documentation for Drupal 8 theming.

Comment: If you are building a D8 theme, you can use `attach_library()` twig method in your twig template.